# Library seasonal x-13arima: error between 36 and 62 points

Tags: r, time-series, arima

Hi Im using the seasonal library in Rstudio, I have a data set of 48 numbers to make a seasonal adjustment, and the function seas() doesn't seems to work.

After several attemps to fix the error I found the problem is in the amount of data:

-Less than 36: not enough data points, series must have at least 3 complete years of data.

-Between 36 and 62 data points appears the following error:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\krafftdi\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGaGNle\x1355813076522/iofile.est': No such file or directory
```

-More than 63 it appears to be working just fine.

I have no idea why it happened that way, I already try to reinstall the library as well as change the working directory but nothing seems to work.

Is it a problem with my library/computer/Rstudio or the library doesn't work?
Can anybody explain to me why the error is in Temporaly files and how can make it work for 48 numbers (ie 4 years)?

Here is an example of my test code:

```
Test <- rnorm(62)
Test.ts <-ts(Test, start = c(2019,1),frequency =12)
seas(Test.ts)
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Error reported here: https://github.com/christophsax/seasonal/issues/296